# How to set font kerning in reportlab python?

Tags: python, reportlab, kerning

I add font to reportlab, then it generates pdf, but text has kerning turned off. For example in html it works as expected. How to enable font kerning in reportlab ? I have tried changing settings in `ParagraphStyle` and `textObject.setCharSpace` but nothing has the desired effect. Below is my sample code and the expected results. Example is available also on my github: https://github.com/czubik8805/ReportLabKerning

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


pdfmetrics.registerFont(
    TTFont(
        'arial',
        'arial.ttf')
)

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
c.setFont('arial', 32)
c.drawString(10, 450, "Toned Avenue")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

[Text from reportlab (without kerning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2eAx.png)

[Text from HTML with (kerning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o668n.png)